# Layerslider autoPauseSlideshow Dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm tring to use this Slider with my page.
The settings for js is here:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    _p.init();      
    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
        autoStart               : true,
        firstLayer              : 2,
        skinsPath : '/static/layerslider/skins/',
        autoPauseSlideshow      : 'auto',
        durationTimeIn : 1500,
        durationTimeOut : 1500

    });
```

Autostart, fistlayer works, but autoPauseSlideshow don't!
I've tryed with the original file of template, and keeps don't working!
Anyone may help me? thanks